# How do you enable or disable a select tag in html using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do you enable or disable a select tag after selecting an option from the first select tag in jQuery, but current version is not working.

```
$("select[name='selectALPHA']").change(function () {
    if ($("select[name='selectBRAVO'"].attr('enabled') == false {
      $("select[name='selectBRAVO']").attr('enabled', 'true');
    }
    else
    {
      $("select[name='selectBRAVO']").attr('enabled', 'false');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so very sure what you are trying to achieve here but I think that this can help you :

```
$("select[name='select1']").change(function () {
    var jSelect2=$("select[name='select2']");

    if($(this).val()){
       jSelect2.removeAttr('disabled');
    }else{
       jSelect2.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }

});
```

See working example here : [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bYFjQ/9/)

Comment: I'm selecting the year in the first select tag, the first option is blank.  If its turns blank again I want to disable it otherwise enable it.

Comment: I have updated the answer and the fiddle to reflect what you want to do.

Comment: the `if/else` could be replaced entirely with `jSelect2.attr('disabled', !$(this).val() );`

Answer (score 4):

[`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr) expects a boolean.

```
$("select[name='selectBRAVO']").attr('disabled', false);
```

The code also contains syntax errors. Fixes:

```
var $bravo = $("select[name='selectBRAVO']");

$("select[name='selectALPHA']").change(function () {
    $bravo.attr('enabled', !$bravo.attr('enabled'));
});
```

Comment: As an example to jQuery website `$("button:gt(1)").attr("disabled","disabled");
` http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2

Comment: Huh. I didn't know that worked, and it's not clear on the [api page](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Comment: `attr()` is basically used to change the value of an element's attribute. @Greg find `$("button:gt(1)").attr("disabled","disabled");
` on the page. As I have said, it is an example.

Comment: @domanokz, I was actually commenting on @Matt Ball's answer, in that I didn't know that `.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` was the same as `.attr('disabled', true)`. The latter does seem more semantic.

Comment: @GregL `.attr()` has caused **a lot** of confusion. The better choice with newer versions of jQuery is [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop).

Comment: @GregL - it "works" because the string "disabled" (or any non-empty string) type converts to `true`, so the disabled attribute is set to true, disabling the control. You can change the value to "false" (or any non-empty string) and the button will still be disabled.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want to toggle the value, in plain js:

```
var select = document.getElementsByName('selectBRAVO')[0];
select.disabled = !select.disabled;
```

I'm sure you can figure out the jQuery equivalent.

#### Edit

Here's one different to Matt's based on Reid's suggestion:

```
var select = $("select[name='selectBRAVO']")[0];
select.disabled = !select.disabled;
```

The old jQuery *attr* method mixed up HTML attributes and DOM properties rather badly. In the new version, *attr* deals only with HTML attributes, which is better. However, in the vast majority of cases, what programmers really want is the DOM property. That can be accessed directly, there is no need to call *attr* or *getAttribute*. Direct property access is (hugely) faster, less to type and easier to read.

Comment: Just for completion's sake, you can extract the DOM element from a jQuery element with either [`.get`](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or using array notation. Examples: `$('a:first').get(0)` or `$('a:first')[0]`.

Comment: Yeah, I know but Matt has a jQuery answer. I hate the `attr` method - it should be avoided even in its new, updated form. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We all know that a select element has an attribute of `disabled`:

```
<select disabled="disabled">
</select>
```

And to manipulate the value of an attribute using jQuery, As an example on http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr2:

```
$("button:gt(1)").attr("disabled","disabled");
```

You can do the same in select element:

```
$("select[name='selectALPHA']").change(function () {
    if ($("select[name='selectBRAVO'"].attr('disabled') == 'disabled'{
      $("select[name='selectBRAVO']").removeAttr('disabled');
    }
    else
    {
      $("select[name='selectBRAVO']").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```